# How does the gerund 'bear, carry'?

Tags: etymology, latin

> [[ Etymonline: ]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=gerund&searchmode=none)
>   1510s, from Latin gerundum "to be carried out," gerundive of *gerere* **"to bear, carry"** (see gest). In Latin, a verbal noun used for all cases of the infinitive but the nominative; applied in English to verbal nouns in -ing. `"So called because according to the old grammarians, the gerund prop[erly] expressed the doing or the necessity of doing something"` [Century Dictionary]. ...

Source: p 32, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* (2005) by Huddleston and Pullum

> Traditionally (for example, in the grammar of Latin), a gerund is a verb-form that
>   is functionally similar to a noun

Despite the above, I don’t understand the choice of **gerund**, especially the greyed quote.
What does this mean: ' for the gerund to `prop[erly]` express ' ?

I heed the Etymological Fallacy, but how is **"to bear, carry"** unique to gerunds?   I read [this](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1029/5306).

Footnote: I'm interested in the foregoing for French also, but [this comment](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12279/how-does-the-gerund-bear-or-carry#comment32996_12279) advised me to redirect.

Comment: In Latin, the *gerundive* `gerundum` literally means "must be carried out/must be done".  There is no *gerundive* in English.  The gerundive, which in form was an adjective, was frequently used to expressive necessity.  Occasionally, it was used to also express the same ideas as the *gerund* which was a non-finite verbal noun form.  I'm not sure what you're asking, though.  Are you asking why a "gerund" is called a ""gerund"?  It's just a name for a grammatical form so named because the name resembled some of its functions (though not all).

Comment: The last link directs the visitor to 404, whatever used to be there has now been deleted.

Comment: There should be a tag "grammar terms". The tags etymology and Latin are rather vague and do not  characterize the problem of this post sufficiently. And I think the discussion of grammar terms - their sense and nonsense - should be a main topic.

Comment: @rogermue +1. Agreed. Please inform me whether I can help.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit -That would be fine. I don't know how to create a new tag. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rogermue You're welcome. I asked about this just now on Meta: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/6941/50720. Please inform me if you mind my citation of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is something mysterious about the term gerund, at least the term does not give a clear insight into this special verb form.

By the way, there were two similar terms: gerundium and gerundive.

It may be that the terms are not derived from gerere, which does not make much sense. I think it might be possible that the terms ultimately came from agere and the vowel a of agerere vanished somehow and the word was muddled up with gerere.

Thinking about the problem of terms, sometimes it is very difficult to invent a term for particular verb forms. With the term participle we have a term that gives some insight into the nature of these special verb forms.

The terms gerund and gerundive are mere labels, giving not much insight and we should invent a new systematic term for gerund such as noun-verb-form.